# Inconsistent Accuracy Score using evaluate_generator on keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I’m trying to solve a problem in my CNN model. I'm using a dataset that is structured as follow:
My data is organized as follow:

- train

  - parasitized
  - uninfected
- test

  - parasitized
  - uninfected
- validation

  - parasitized
  - uninfected

My dataset is too large and i'm using ImageDataGenerator to preprocess the images and also upload them in batches (reduce computational cost). In a first i configured the ImageDataGenerator as follows:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

#Define a ImageDataGenerator for each dataset. 
#This augmentation process is only to rescale each imagem to 1/255

datagen_train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) #rescale=1./255
datagen_test = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
datagen_valid = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

#Define a batch_size parameter
batch_size=32

# Here .flow_from_directory is used to transform 
train_generator = datagen_train.flow_from_directory(
    'content/cell_images/train', #Train folder path 
    target_size=(150,150), #all images will be resized to 150x150
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical') # We use categorical_crossentropy loss, 
                              # we need categorical labels


test_generator = datagen_test.flow_from_directory(
    'content/cell_images/test', #Test folder path
    target_size=(150,150), #all images will be resized to 150x150
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')         

valid_generator = datagen_valid.flow_from_directory(
    'content/cell_images/valid',
     target_size=(150,150),
     batch_size=32,
     class_mode='categorical')
```

To fit the model it was used fit_generator and a checkpointer to save the best weights based on the validation_accuracy:

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

# Define epochs number
epochs = 10

# Create a checkpointer to save only the best params
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='cnn_model.weights.best.hdf5', 
                          verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
               steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples//batch_size,
               epochs=epochs,
               callbacks=[checkpointer],
               validation_data=valid_generator,
               validation_steps=valid_generator.samples//batch_size)
```

And finally, the best weights was loaded to the model. The model was evaluated using test_set:

```
# load the weights that yielded the best validation accuracy
model.load_weights('cnn_model.weights.best.hdf5')

#evaluate and print test accuracy
score = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator,
       test_generator.samples//batch_size)
print('\n', 'Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

But, here is my problem: each time i run only the `model.evaluate_generator` without train the model again (i.e. keeping the same weights), it returns different accuracy scores.

I've been looking for a solution, reading a lot of posts to get some insights and recently i got some advance.

Recently, i discovered based on [this post](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-image-classification-with-keras-flow-from-directory-and-generators-95f75ebe5720) that if i set `Shuffle=True` and `batch_size=1` in test_generator:

```
test_generator = datagen_test.flow_from_directory(
    'content/cell_images/test', #Test folder path
    target_size=(150,150), #all images will be resized to 150x150
    batch_size=1,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False)`
```

and `steps = test_generator.samples in test_generator`: 
`score = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, test_generator.samples)`

the values doesn't change any more.

I was investigating the effect of rescale 1./255 based on [this post](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6499). For this, i used callbacks with a checkpointer to save the weights only for the best validation socore. After, i loaded the best weights to the model and evaluated using model.evaluate_generator, as mentioned above. To check the score consistency i also use the validation score to check if the values returned by the callbacks for the best weights is the same returned by the evaluate_generator. Before run the evaluate_generator with validation_set i used the same params of the test set:

```
valid_generator = datagen_valid.flow_from_directory(
    'content/cell_images/valid',
    target_size=(150,150),
    batch_size=1,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False)


#evaluate and print test accuracy
score = model.evaluate_generator(valid_generator, 
        valid_generator.samples)
print('\n', 'Valid accuracy:', score[1])

#evaluate and print test accuracy
score = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, 
test_generator.samples)
print('\n', 'Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Curiously i noticed that:

**When i don't use the rescale (1./255):**

`datagen_train = ImageDataGenerator()`

`datagen_test = ImageDataGenerator()`

`datagen_valid = ImageDataGenerator()`

the validation_score displayed by the callbacks (0.5) it's exacly the same obtained from model.evaluate_generator (0.5); Also, the test set returns an accuracy score = 0.5.

**When i use the rescale (1./255):**

`datagen_train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)`

`datagen_test = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)`

`datagen_valid = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)`

the difference between validation_score displayed by the callbacks (0.9515):

```
Epoch 7/10
688/688 [==============================] - 67s 97ms/step - loss: 
0.2017 - acc: 0.9496 - val_loss: 0.1767 - val_acc: 0.9515

Epoch 00007: val_loss improved from 0.19304 to 0.17671, saving model 
to cnn_model.weights.best.hdf5
```

and the score obtained from  model.evaluate_generator (`Valid accuracy: 0.9466618287373004`) it's very tiny; Using test set - 
`Test accuracy: 0.9078374455732946`

Based on  this small difference between validation scores, could i infer that the evaluate_generator is working corrreclty? And, could i infer that the accuracy score on the test_set is also correctly ? Or there is another approach to solve this problem?

I'm frustating with this problem. 
Sorry for the long post, i'm trying to be the more didactic i can.

Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved!

Comment: how did you solve this?